# Getting jquery autocomplete suggestion list on select or enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-widgets

I'm looking for some help customizing the jQuery autocomplete widget. I'm using autocomplete on some big arrays and showing a few of the results in the suggestions. When the user hits enter (or selects a value, enter would be nice too though), I want to get the list of suggestions into an array so I can display them elsewhere.

This is pretty close to what I want, I'm going to keep playing with it and hopefully figure this out on my own:

HTML

```
<input id="autocomplete"/>
<div class="test">Output goes here:<br/><ul></ul></div>
```

JS

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    search: function(event, ui) {
        $('.test ul').empty();
    },
    source: ["something", "something-else"]
}).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

    return $('<li/>')
   .data('item.autocomplete', item)
   .append(item.value)
   .appendTo($('.test ul'));
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uMqyn/1/

Thanks!

Comment: How many do you want to "select" at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that might get you started - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/uMqyn/563/).

Use the "response" function to pull out the returned variables with `ui.content[n].value` and then put them where you wish.

JS

```
$('.autocomp').autocomplete({
    autoFocus : true,
    source : areas,
    selectFirst : true,
    response: function( event, ui ) { 
        for(var n=0; n<5; n++)
        {
         $('.test').append( ui.content[n].value + '<br />' );
         console.log( ui.content[n].value );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uMqyn/565/

```
var areas = ['california', 'nevada', 'oregon', 'utah', 'arizona', 'new mexico', 'minnesota', 'texas', 'louisiana', 'alabama', 'mississippi', 'oklahoma', 'washington'];

var foo;
$('.autocomp').autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: areas,
    delay: 0,
    response: function (event, ui) {
        foo = ui.content;
    }
});

$(".autocomp").keypress(function (e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {
        $('.autocomp').autocomplete('close');
        if (foo.length) {
            $(".test").empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
                $(".test").append(foo[i].value + '<br>');
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```